# Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
s1 = "INSERT INTO call_requests ([id_users], [id_call_request_types], [id_call_request_statuses], [id_user_contact_types], [id_countries], [contact_value], [contact_name], [time_start], [time_end], [call_request_note], [date_add], [id_user_sessions]) VALUES (" & IIf(id_users > 0, id_users, "NULL") & ", " & id_call_request_types & ", " & id_call_request_statuses & ", " & id_user_contact_types & ", " & id_countries & ", '" & contact_value & "', '" & Replace(contact_name, "'", Chr(34)) & "', " & Nz(time_start, "Null") & ", " & Nz(time_end, "Null") & ", '" & Nz(call_request_note, "") & "', " & DateWinToJet(date_add) & "," & IIf(id_user_sessions > 0, id_user_sessions, "Null") & ")"
```

Вот что выдает `debug.print s1`:

```
INSERT INTO [call_requests] ([id_users], [id_call_request_types], [id_call_request_statuses], [id_user_contact_types], [id_countries], [contact_value], [contact_name], [time_start], [time_end], [call_request_note], [date_add], [id_user_sessions]) VALUES (104696, 8, 1, 1, 170, '92458******', '', 0, 0, '', ,Null)
```

Comment: Вот какой толк от кода сборки? показывайте `Debug.Print s1`...

Comment: @Akina исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последние 3 параметра: «`'', ,Null)`»

Вместо пропуска в предпоследнем нужно вставлять NULL

Answer (score 2):

Собранный запрос, но в форматированном виде:

```sql
INSERT INTO [call_requests] ([id_users], 
                             [id_call_request_types], 
                             [id_call_request_statuses], 
                             [id_user_contact_types], 
                             [id_countries], 
                             [contact_value], 
                             [contact_name], 
                             [time_start], 
                             [time_end], 
                             [call_request_note], 
                             [date_add], 
                             [id_user_sessions]) 
VALUES (104696, 
        8, 
        1, 
        1, 
        170, 
        '92458******', 
        '', 
        0, 
        0, 
        '', 
        ,       /* вот тут заведомая ерунда */
        Null)
```

Очевидная ошибка (указал [Герман Борисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183614/%d0%93%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%91%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) в своём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1053347/229437)) - вообще отсутствует значение для поля `date_add`. Следует указать либо Null, либо некое дефолтное значение, либо, как для полей `time_start` и `time_end`, ноль.

Менее очевидные... не то чтобы ошибки (значения-то запишутся), но способны привести к проблемам - нули для полей `time_start` и `time_end`. Лучше некое дефолтное значение - скажем, в далёком, но валидном прошлом. Впрочем, зависит от реального типа поля.